# Error running PHP: Xdebug port 9000 is busy

Tags: xdebug

I set config in PhpStorm to run Xdebug on Docker. Trying to debug PHP script outputs in PhpStorm event log with:

> "Error running script.php: Port 9000 is busy"

I change port but didn't work the same problem

-config file xdebug.ini

```
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=10000
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/php5-xdebug.log
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the port in the PhpStorm configuration/settings too. It's PhpStorm that needs to open the port and listen, not Xdebug.

And, if you're using PHP-FPM, it already has the port 9000 open, as they unfortunately choose the same port.

Comment: yes, xdebug dll internally inside php uses different random local port, port 9000 is usually, is a remote port, that phpstorm message as you told is very common when it clashes on the local side = host pc